# Ask for confirmation before article publish

Tags: com-content

How we can add confirm dialog before publishing or unpublish article in Joomla ?
I want to add confirmation box before publish or unpublish, I want same for custom component also, how i can achive this?
Please guide

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by adding the following code to the very end of your `/administrator/components/com_content/views/tmpl/edit.php`:

```
<script>
    jQuery("#jform_state").on('change', function(e){
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to change the status of this article?") != true) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
</script>
```

A better idea is to copy the `edit.php` file to the corresponding location of your admin template and then make the modification there.